# Using efficient net as feature extractor for meta/Few shot learning in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction

I am working on few shot learning and I wanted to use efficient-net as backbone feature extractor. Most of the model use Resnet as feature extractor. For example I can use below line of code and it extract features for me -

```
from model.res50 import ResNet
self.encoder = ResNet()
self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)
def forward(self, data):
    out = self.encoder(data)
    out = self.fc(out)
    return out
```

I am using this PyTorch implemetation of Efficientnet- [EfficientNet-PyTorch](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/master/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py). I am not sure how to use this effcientnet as feature extractor as I did with Resnet. Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you should use it in exactly the same way. Both are classification models nominally designed for ImageNet classification, so the default configuration of each should output a vector of length 1000. So I don't think there's any difference in how you treat the output of one versus the other

Comment: thanks for your comment, will try it in same way and see if it can extract feature or not.